# Layout in Razor generated views not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorgenerator

I am have created two projects, where `Main` is the main project and `WebApp` as the second one. I am using RazorGenerator to call the Areas in my `WebApp` from `Main`.

I can access `~/Test/Default/Index` of `WebApp`, however it seems that the Layout code in the _ViewStart.cshtml is not working. I am ending up with just a simple code, without the scaffold _Layout created by Visual Studio.

[What the output looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThoUr.png)

This is the code in my Index. I scaffolded everything from creating an Area, controller and View. The only thing I added was the `@* Generator: MvcView *@` in the index.

```
@* Generator: MvcView *@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
```

Is there any reason why the View cannot show the layout as well?

Comment: View should have line like this to be associated with layout:
"Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml";"

Comment: Yes. That's in my ViewStart.cshtml. Tried placing a breakpoint on the line, it seems that the program is not going there.

Comment: I mean in your index view.